# Getting Permission Denied for Selenium Manager when running selenium grid via docker compose

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Tests fail as the selenium web driver cannot find executable browser drivers. And selenium manager is not able to work because permission was denied.

WARNING: IOException running command [/tmp/selenium-manager6934959080002692789801225066774/selenium-manager, --driver, chromedriver]: Cannot run program "/tmp/selenium-manager6934959080002692789801225066774/selenium-manager": error=13, Permission denied

Please let me know how to handle this issue.